# Finite group of two generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My question is simple :

Any finite group of two generators is cyclic, semidirect sum, or direct sum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The group [$A_5$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group) is generated by $(123)$ and $(12345)$. It isn't cyclic and cannot be represented as a nontrivial semidirect product, let alone a direct product.

Answer (score 3):

None of the above.

A group generated by two elements is not necessarily cyclic...That requires that a group be generated by one element.

Consider, now, the dihedral group [$D_8$](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/D8), which is generated by two elements. It isn't cyclic and it can't be represented as a (non-trivial) direct product.

Nor is it necessarily a semidirect product. As Dan suggests: consider the alternating group $A_5$ which can be generated by two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Every symmetric group $S_n$ is generated by two elements $(1,2,\ldots,n)$ and $(1,2)$. Every group is embedded into a symmetric one. So the structure of groups with two generators can be arbitrarily complicated.